# How to find actual DNS TTL values

Tags: linux, dns

I've been trying to figure out a reliable way to find out the various TTL values for different DNS records on unix.
To clarify, what I want to find is the **actual TTL**, not the cached TTL values.

For example, google.com's A record has a TTL of 300 seconds. The same record has been cached on my system, with a TTL value of 96 seconds. What I want to find is the 300 second, not the 96 seconds.

So far I've tried using the following:

```
nslookup -query=SOA google.com | grep 'origin' # Find authoritative name server of domain
# origin = ns1.google.com
dig +nocmd +noall +answer @ns1.google.com www.google.com # Find TTL value of subdomain
# www.google.com.         300     IN      A       74.125.130.106
```

This works fine, but is there a better alternative that is faster or better yet, allows me to list all the dns records under a specified primary domain and their TTLs?

Comment: " I want to find is the actual TTL, not the cached TTL values. " You have to query the authoritative nameservers, not the recursive ones. You have to start from the root, or at least the authoritative nameservers of the parent of the domain you are interested in, to learn of its `NS` records and then query them.

Comment: "allows me to list all the dns records under a specified primary domain and their TTLs?" No that does not exist in general for any zone you do not control.